# iptables DNAT port forward to another machine on LAN

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, nat, port-forwarding, ufw

I am trying to implement iptables forwarding rules in order to internally redirect packets coming through a specific port.

My machine is running under the distribution *Ubuntu Server 12.04.3*, with UFW and all the latest updates.

So far, I was able to establish a partially-working setup, shown hereafter:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 40591 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.100:40591
iptables -A ufw-user-forward -p tcp -d 192.168.0.100 --dport 40591 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A ufw-user-forward -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

As shown in the block, the destination recipient is *192.168.0.100* and the port *40591*.

However, issues arose shortly after, I noticed my apache2 service was outputting LOTS of errors; my PHP scripts were no longer able to connect to my database via *127.0.0.1*, as connections were purportedly initiated from its LAN address *(192.168.0.10*).

In order to confirm the source of the problem, I have tried:

1. *strace*-ing my PHP script, but no conclusive information was spat out, aside from confirming what I already knew (i.e. connections being initiated locally and magically deflected to the server's local address (*192.168.0.10*))
2. *tcpdump*-ing on port 3306 with the command `tcpdump -e -i any -n -s0 tcp port 3306`

### tcpdump

**Before** (adding the rules)

```
04:51:30.043660  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [S], seq 1373736824, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 33638495 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
04:51:30.043679  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46461: Flags [S.], seq 3532787939, ack 1373736825, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 33638495 ecr 33638495,nop,wscale 7], length 0
04:51:30.043692  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638495 ecr 33638495], length 0
04:51:30.043935  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 163: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46461: Flags [P.], seq 1:96, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638495 ecr 33638495], length 95
04:51:30.043992  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [.], ack 96, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638495 ecr 33638495], length 0
04:51:30.044044  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 173: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [P.], seq 1:106, ack 96, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638495 ecr 33638495], length 105
04:51:30.044077  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46461: Flags [.], ack 106, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638495 ecr 33638495], length 0
04:51:30.044152  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 79: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46461: Flags [P.], seq 96:107, ack 106, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638495 ecr 33638495], length 11
04:51:30.044240  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 115: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [P.], seq 106:153, ack 107, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638495 ecr 33638495], length 47
04:51:30.044560  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 413: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46461: Flags [P.], seq 107:452, ack 153, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638496 ecr 33638495], length 345
04:51:30.052507  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 204: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [P.], seq 153:289, ack 452, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638498 ecr 33638496], length 136
04:51:30.052907  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 471: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46461: Flags [P.], seq 452:855, ack 289, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638498 ecr 33638498], length 403
04:51:30.053042  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 302: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [P.], seq 289:523, ack 855, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638498 ecr 33638498], length 234
04:51:30.092217  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 79: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46461: Flags [P.], seq 855:866, ack 523, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638507 ecr 33638498], length 11
04:51:30.092377  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 73: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [P.], seq 523:528, ack 866, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638508 ecr 33638507], length 5
04:51:30.092404  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [F.], seq 528, ack 866, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638508 ecr 33638507], length 0
04:51:30.092427  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46461: Flags [F.], seq 866, ack 529, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638508 ecr 33638508], length 0
04:51:30.092446  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 127.0.0.1.46461 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [.], ack 867, win 359, options [nop,nop,TS val 33638508 ecr 33638508], length 0
```

**After**

```
04:32:38.264052  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.0.10.46454 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [S], seq 344014396, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 33355550 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
04:32:38.264072  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46454: Flags [S.], seq 1406967667, ack 344014397, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 33355550 ecr 33355550,nop,wscale 7], length 0
04:32:38.264086  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 192.168.0.10.46454 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [.], ack 1406967668, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33355550 ecr 33355550], length 0
04:32:38.264337  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 141: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46454: Flags [P.], seq 1:74, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33355551 ecr 33355550], length 73
04:32:38.264388  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46454: Flags [F.], seq 74, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33355551 ecr 33355550], length 0
04:32:38.264450  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 192.168.0.10.46454 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [.], ack 74, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33355551 ecr 33355551], length 0
04:32:38.264488  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 192.168.0.10.46454 > 127.0.0.1.3306: Flags [F.], seq 0, ack 75, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33355551 ecr 33355551], length 0
04:32:38.264506  In 00:00:00:00:00:00 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 68: 127.0.0.1.3306 > 127.0.0.1.46454: Flags [.], ack 2, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 33355551 ecr 33355551], length 0
```

Ergo, my setup has gone haywire and I'm not quite sure how to implement a stable, NAT-ed forward setup using iptables rules.

So my question is: what is causing this issue and how could I remedy to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me if you're doing this on a single-homed or dual-homed machine. You're not specifying any interfaces in your `iptables` rules and that has me puzzled.

It looks to me like the `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE` rule is your culprit. That's going to cause outgoing traffic on all your interfaces to be SNAT'ted to the interface's IP address. I don't think you want that. You should be specifying your Internet-facing interface on that rule as the `-o` interface.

Comment: I will try and do some research on my end about masquerading and see what I get, I'll post my results. FYI: I only have a single interface aside from `lo`; my machine is single-homed.

Comment: Is the box single-homed or multi-homed?

Comment: See my edit; (Single homed)

Comment: Well, it seems like that you were right. The problem was indeed due to not specifying any interface, which I fixed by changing my DNAT rule to `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -o eth0`. Thanks! — scratch that, I'm still getting issues.

Comment: After all, that's the only thing that was required to make this shoddy setup work; I had to make some (unrelated) trivial minor tweaks in order to get everything running correctly.

Comment: Glad I could help.